# Bootstrap - dropdownlist with button to the right, but form-control makes it 100% width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with getting my 'Create' button to be right of my dropdownlist. Because the dropdown has a class `form-control` it makes the width 100% of the space available and so my button wraps underneath. If I remove the class the button sits next to the dropdown.

http://jsfiddle.net/2y39drrh/

Rather than writing a CSS class to override form-control's width, is there a better way? The forms.less file does say to use `form-control` with `<select>` elements...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="Note_NoteTypeId">Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true"> 
      <option value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="3">Option1</option>
      <option value="2">Option2</option>
      <option value="1">Option3</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnCreate" type="button">Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this?

**Example 1**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true"> 
      <option value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="3">Option1</option>
      <option value="2">Option2</option>
      <option value="1">Option3</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnCreate" type="button">Create</button>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```
<div class="form-inline">
<select class="form-control" data-val="true"> 
      <option value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="3">Option1</option>
      <option value="2">Option2</option>
      <option value="1">Option3</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Create">
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, that helped me get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, the code I'm inserting to this post works weird on JSFiddle and SO editor. But it works fine on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/almond/pen/RaozYa)

```css
body {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 2em;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="vehicle" name="vehicle" class="form-control" data-dropupauto="false">
        <option value=""> 1 </option>
        <option value=""> 2 </option>                                         <option value=""> 3 </option>      
         </select>


      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnCreate" type="button">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

See the example in full page. I believe that's the reason why SO editor and JSFiddle shows different results.